# fadein and fadeout div in a loop - jquery

Tags: jquery, fadein, fade, fadeout

I have the following jquery which will fade elements in and out in order :

```
var $zfader = jQuery.noConflict();
$zfader(document).ready(function(){
$zfader('.fadethis .fade');
    setInterval(function(){
        $zfader('.fadethis .fade').filter(':visible').fadeOut(2000,function(){
            if($zfader(this).next('.fade').size()){
                $zfader(this).next().fadeIn(1000);
            }
            else{
                $zfader('.fadethis .fade').eq(0).fadeIn(1000);
            }
        });
    },10000);   
});
```

html :

```
    <div class="container fadethis">
        <div class="fade">number one</div>
        <div class="fade" style="display:none">number two</div>
    </div>
```

The problem is I do not want to use the display:none... I was thinking setting a position:absolute on .fade so they are all 'on top' of each other and acheiving the same effect with opacity?  Secondly, I want to ensure if JavaScript is off that only the first shows...

Comment: Sigh, it was all going so good until the java comment.. (and now edited out by Matt - thx Matt!)

Comment: What is wrong with `display:none;`? Perhaps you could use `visibility:hidden;` if you want to preserve that white space.

Comment: As @TravisJ said, what's wrong with `display:none`? What exactly are you trying to achieve here? Could you create a [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Purely for the fact I try to stay away from display:none as it as seen negatively in the eyes of the big G (Google) for seo purposes and it will contain actual text... don't want it to appear as if I am stuffing hidden keywords.

Comment: Use `css` or `hide` methods for hiding the elements, `$('.fade').hide();`

Comment: Doesn't hide use `display:none;`?

Comment: The script really isn't that big of a deal I suppose as script and noscript could be used in the page to set a default.

Comment: `jQuery: hide: for ( i = 0; i < j; i++ ) {
    this[i].style.display = "none";
   }`, although I suppose if you did this after the page loaded seo would have been able to access the element.

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/LtA8H/ - is the default I have now.

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is SEO, it doesn't matter how you make the div less visible, it will hurt you if it is considered to be difficult to see and thus possibly keyword stuffing. Search engines like Google do not just check display:none; but also if text is the same color as the background, opacity being too low on text, etc.

If you're concerned about SEO, you might want to rethink your design. Why do you want this fade effect? Is it helping the layout of your information? Does the user feel like they are better able to access the information? If not, redesign.

Comment: Simply a rotating comment on the index page... purely visual to the user and looks better visually than just having a single default all the time.

Comment: That shouldn't hurt your SEO then, display: none; should be a fine way to go

Answer (score 0):

If you want seo, but when javascript is disabled you don't want the element to show, you can <strike>draw the element off screen</strike> minimize the element, with a class, like this:

```
.minimize
{
 position: absolute;
 height: 0px;
 width: 0px;
}​
```

Then remove that class in your script like this:

```
$zfader('.minimize').removeClass('minimize');
```

You can change a little of the style to make your elements overlap like this:

```
style="position:absolute;vertical-align:top;"
```

Here is the final solution (with jsfiddle example)

html:

```
<div>Some Space</div>
<div class="container fadethis">
 <div class="fade" style="position:absolute;vertical-align:top;">number one</div>
 <div class="fade minimize" style="position:absolute;vertical-align:top;">number two</div>
</div>​
```

css:

```
.minimize
{
 position: absolute;
 height: 0px;
 width: 0px;
}  ​
```

js:

```
var $zfader = jQuery.noConflict();
$zfader(document).ready(function(){
 $zfader('.fadethis .fade').eq(1).hide();
 $zfader('.minimize').removeClass('minimize');
 setInterval(function(){
  var hidden = $zfader('.fadethis .fade').filter(':hidden');
  var visible = $zfader('.fadethis .fade').filter(':visible');
  visible.fadeOut(2000,function(){
   hidden.fadeIn(1000);
  });
 },10000);
});​
```

jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/3FQDL/4/

Comment: Pretty sure drawing off screen is a detected "hiding stuff" method in regards to SEO, but since the content he is displaying isn't main content, it shouldn't hurt his rankings

Comment: @spex - I will edit the content, perhaps hiding it off screen can be dangerous for seo.